# Use threading.Event() to send SSE event in Django project after receiving message from RabbitMQ

Tags: python, django, django-views, rabbitmq, server-sent-events

I have a Django map application that displays real-time markers with either red or green color based on the marker's state, which is updated when a new message arrives. Currently, I'm periodically updating the page every 3 seconds, but I want to achieve a more efficient approach by updating the page only after a change in the database.

I have this sse function in my views.py:

```
from threading import Event
marker_update_event = Event()
marker_update_event_list = {0: marker_update_event}
#print("Marker update event created", marker_update_event_list[0])

def sse(request):
    def event_stream():
        while True:
            marker_data = []
            all_markers = Marker.objects.all()
            for marker in all_markers:
                latest_message = marker.get_latest_message()
                marker_data.append({
                    'name': marker.get_name(),
                    'latitude': marker.get_latitude(),
                    'longitude': marker.get_longitude(),
                    'error_type': latest_message.get_error_type() if latest_message else 'No error type',
                    'message': latest_message.get_message() if latest_message else 'No messages',
                    'state': marker.get_state(),
                    'id': marker.id,
                })

            if marker_update_event_list[0].is_set():
                print('marker_update_event is set')
                yield 'event: marker_data\ndata: %s\n\n' % json.dumps(marker_data)
                marker_update_event_list[0].clear()
            marker_update_event_list[0].wait()


    return StreamingHttpResponse(event_stream(), content_type="text/event-stream")
```

I'm also consuming messages from RabbitMQ using a consumer.py script at the root directory:

```
import json
import pika
import django

# Django environment setup

from markers.models import Message
from markers.views import marker_update_event_list

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue='messages')

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    data = json.loads(body)

    if properties.content_type == 'message_created':
        message = Message.objects.create(error_type=data['error_type'], message=data['message'], date=data['date'], marker_id=data['id'])
        message.save()
        marker_update_event_list[0].set()

    elif properties.content_type == 'message_updated':
        message = Message.objects.create(error_type=data['error_type'], message=data['message'], date=data['date'], marker_id=data['id'])
        message.save()
        marker_update_event_list[0].set()

channel.basic_consume(queue='messages', on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)

print('Started Consuming')

channel.start_consuming()
```

The problem I'm facing is that when I run python consumer.py, it creates an instance of threading.Event(). Running python manage.py runserver also creates another instance of threading.Event(). Consequently, the instance in views.py remains False, and the instance in consumer.py becomes True after receiving a single message. That way, the page is never updated.

How can I ensure that both consumer.py and views.py share the same threading.Event() instance for real-time updates on the webpage?

I also have signals.py file in my project that updates the Marker state after a new Message. I tried to implement this in that file, too. But, I encountered the same problem. Different instances are created.